# How do I identify a MacBook Pro from its serial number?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

[This article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4132) on identifying a MacBook Pro lists the serial number as one method of identifying it. However, the [article it links to](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1366), doesn't explain how to identify it either. How can I identify a Macbook Pro from its serial number.

Comment: Try here: http://www.powerbookmedic.com/identify-mac-serial.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enter the serial number in Apple's [Warranty coverage checker](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) (if you don't remember the URL, there's a link to it in the "AppleCare and warranty" section of Apple's main [support page](http://support.apple.com/).  It'll tell you the model name, as well as the warranty status.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Comment: @FlorianF I've updated them; thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

EveryMac has a serial number identification tool as well:

http://www.everymac.com/mac-identification/index-how-to-identify-my-mac.html